# AndroidManifest как убрать часть функций?

Tags: java, android, xml

Сделал такого вида манифест, всё работает, но  при установке приложения андроид мне пишет что данное приложение будет иметь следующие функции, которые я вообще не использую в своём приложении:

```
* снимать фото и видео
* записывать аудио
* управление вибросигналом
```

Как мне их "выпилить" из манифеста?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jack.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGEE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".register"
        android:label="@string/register" />
    <activity
        android:name=".dialogs"
        android:label="@string/dialogs" />
    <activity
        android:name=".messages"
        android:label="@string/messages" />

    <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MessagesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messages"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти разрешения требуются в каких-то либах, подключённых к вашему проекту. Вам надо или:

1. Смириться с их требованиями
2. Или удалить эти зависимости
3. Или самостоятельно исправить эти либы так, чтобы они не требовали этих разрешений